# Is it possible to insert date automatically in one cell in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want to insert date in a column automatically when I fill something in a column.
Lets Have an example.

### A1->name

### B1->date

when I fill a name in A2, date is automatically inserted in B2. Is it possible, if yes, Please tell me.

Comment: You could write a macro

Comment: @shree.pat18 PLEASE TELL ME HOW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, its possible using google app script

here is the code

```
function onEdit(event) {

  var aCell = event.source.getActiveCell(), col = aCell.getColumn(); 
  var sheetName = event.source.getActiveSheet().getName(); 
  if(col == 1) {

    var adjacentCell = aCell.offset(0, 2);  
    if(!adjacentCell.getValue()) { 
      var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
                                         "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
      adjacentCell.setValue(newDate);
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with `=if(A1="","",today())` for example but I guessing that won't suit because the inserted date will change as time goes on, unless converted to a value.

Labour saving, but not automatic, might be just enter `name` and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`;`.

Today's date that does not automatically update is a choice between manual entry, that does not suit, or a script.